# Compact alternatives to UUID as a correlationId

Tags: java, random

I am adding correlationIDs to our public and private APIs. This is to be able to trace a request progress through logs.
UUIDs being long strings, take up much space. I need a compact alternative to UUID as a correlation ID.

It will be ok, if a correlationId repeats after a fix period (say 2 months) since the API requests older than that won't be required to be traced.

I have considered using `java.util.Random nextLong()`. But it does not guarantee  that it won't repeat.

Also, `SecureRandom` can pose some performance issues is what I understand and also, I don't need the correlationIDs to be secure.

It would be good to have other options considered.

Comment: What is the reason for not using/preferring a UUID? I have seen services that use UUID as trace id (plus maybe you could suffix it with timestamp)

Comment: UUID strings are big, so, to save log-space, I want other alternative.

Comment: Timestamp (epoch) is an option but will not be unique (I assume you want to use it for a service which runs across machines)

Comment: What about using a timestamp, like `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()` ? Both methods return a `long`.

Comment: yes, the timestamp won't be unique across multiple requests being processed concurrently.

Comment: You say that "`SecureRandom` can pose some performance issues".  Have you tried using `SecureRandom` or another cryptographic RNG in your  application?  If so, was the performance acceptable?  In any case, using a random number generator (especially `SecureRandom` which is what `java.util.UUID` probably uses, too) may be the most appropriate for your goal of generating IDs.

Comment: Consider to use Brave/ Zipkin/ Spring Cloud Sleuth

Comment: Also, what would be an acceptable length of IDs for your purposes, if not the length of UUIDs?

Comment: Take the first or last N characters of a UUID, where N is the String length you can tolerate.

Comment: @PeterO., yeah, I have not tried using SecureRandom. But Looking up other people's discussions , like https://github.com/zalando/logbook/issues/198, I thought it right impose performance issue.

Comment: Upto 8 characters will be an acceptable length for me.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, using first or last N characters will take-away the uniqueness and we can't predict the collision with that at all, right?

Comment: It depends on which N characters you take.  A UUID is not a random hexadecimal number.  There's an algorithm for generating the UUID.  [Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format)

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept IDs up to 8 characters long, the number of possible IDs depends on the character set of those IDs.

- For hexadecimal characters (16-character set), the number of IDs is 4294967296 or 2^32.
- For A-Z, 0-9 (36-character set), the number of IDs is 2821109907456 or about 2^41.
- For base64 or base64url, 0-9 (63-character set), the number of IDs is 248155780267521 or about 2^47.

You should decide which character set to use, as well as ask yourself whether your application can check IDs for randomness and whether you can tolerate the risk of duplicate IDs (so that you won't have a problem generating them randomly using `SecureRandom`). Also note the following:

- The risk of duplicates depends on the number of possible IDs. Roughly speaking, after your application generates the square root of all possible IDs *at random*, the risk of duplicates becomes non-negligible (which in the case of hexadecimal IDs, will occur after just 65536 IDs). See "[Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)" for a more precise statement and formulas.
- If your application is distributed across multiple computers, you might choose to assign each computer a unique value to include in the ID.
- If you don't care about whether your correlation IDs are secure, you might choose to create unique IDs by doing a reversible operation on sequential IDs, such as a reversible mixing function or a linear congruential generator.
- You say that `SecureRandom` "can pose some performance issues". You won't know if it will unless you try it and measure your application's performance. Generating IDs with `SecureRandom` may or may not be too slow for your purposes.

For further considerations and advice, see what I write on "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)".